# Python/Kivy speech recognition failing on Macbook

Tags: python, macos, kivy-language

I am using [Kivy](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwihl9fNhvuDAxVyVPEDHX6tB0kQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fkivy.org%2F&usg=AOvVaw2sQzH6hugoCP4InvINovCg&opi=89978449) for Python UI to do speech to text using Speech Recognition.

I have the following code:

```py
def record_and_transcribe(self, dt):
        recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            try:
                audio = recognizer.listen(source)  # Listen for 1 second
                text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
                self.label.text += text + " "
            except sr.UnknownValueError:
                pass  # Ignore if speech is not understood
            except sr.RequestError as e:
                print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))
```

This code terminates due to the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy/speech_to_text.py", line 24, in record_and_transcribe
     audio = recognizer.listen(source)  # Listen for 1 second
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 465, in listen
     assert source.stream is not None, "Audio source must be entered before listening, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?"
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 AssertionError: Audio source must be entered before listening, see documentation for ``AudioSource``; are you using ``source`` outside of a ``with`` statement?
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

I have tried to look for microphone settings in my system settings, but I do not see Python in the list. Moreover, both Visual Studio Code and Terminal has permissions for microphones, but when I run only the Python code without Kivy, I still get the same error. How can I fix this?

OS: macOS Ventura 13.6.3
IDE: Visual Studio Code